# How to create grid with radiobutton

Tags: gridview, drop-down-menu, yii

In my Yii application, I want to a create gridview with fields "Level of user" and "Complexity of Question".

> Level            |   Complexity
>
> ---
>
> 1. Beginner         |
> 2. Intermediate     |
> 3. Easy             |

In complexity section I want to create a dropdownbox having three fields - hard,medium,easy - for each level so that the user will select the complexity from the dropdownbox. So can you please suggest to me how to create it in Yii how to create it. I am new to Yii,please help me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, please show what you have tried.

Comment: <?php
 $dp=new CActiveDataProvider('Complexity');
  $this->widget('ext.groupgridview.GroupGridView', array(
      'id' => 'grid1',
      'dataProvider' => $dp,
      'mergeColumns' => array('QuestionId'),  
      'columns' => array(
        'Level',
        'Complexity' 
      ),
    ));?>

Answer (score 0):

One way, is in your CGridView widget, under the columns call a method like so:

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name'          =>  'field_name',
        'value'         =>  'Model::model()->methodName()',
        'type'          =>  'text',         
    ),
    ...
```

So, the field_name value if the attributes (the field in the table) name, for example id, user_id etc...

The Model:: bit is the model name in which you are going to have your method, and the methodName() bit is the name of the method (function) you are calling.

No you can simply write a method to render our the HTML to create the radiobuttons (or dropdown list, your question title and content don't make sense). So you could probably use your User model, and create a method called renderRadiobuttons(), which get's called as above.

If you want more specific help, post some code snippets

Comment: Thanx for your guide. Actually i have Complexity form,with QuestionId,LevelId,ComplexityId as there fields. In Grid table i just want three entries as begginer level,Intermediate level,Expert level as radio buttons. For each of these three levels i want to provide complexities as easy,medium and hard in form of dropdownbox. So that when form will load,,,user first will select its level and also will select complexity of question from dropdownbox. And all these fields selected data needs to be get stored in my Complexity table.  So can you please help me in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully. Could you maybe post an image with a kind of flow of what needs to happen and I'll try help you

Comment: Level      |      complexity
® Begginer  level    | Dropdownbox with values as hard,medium,Easy
®Intermediate level  | Dropdownbox with values as hard,medium,Easy
®Expert level      |  Dropdownbox with values as hard,medium,Easy
Radiobuttons are there with each level. User will first select level  by selecting one of the check-box and then will select complexity from dropdown box.I want to create gridview as above. And also want to save selected values of level and complexity in table.  can you please suggest me how to create it